# as2 - form post

Tags: forms, post, actionscript-2

Is it possible to POST a few variables to a new browser window (_blank for example) in as2? I can't seem to find any examples via Google.

Obviously for GET I could use getURL(url,target) but I can't find any similar functions for post.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LoadVars.send method.

> public send(url: String, target: String, [method: String]) : Boolean
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **url**: String - A string; the URL to which to upload variables.
>
> **target**: String - A string; the browser window or frame in which any
>    response will appear. You can enter the name of a specific window or
>    select from the following reserved target names:
>
> "_self" specifies the current frame in the current window. "_blank"
>    specifies a new window. "_parent" specifies the parent of the current
>    frame. "_top" specifies the top-level frame in the current window.
>
> **method**: String [optional] - A string; the GET or POST method of the
>    HTTP protocol. The default value is POST.